# How to automatically stub out dependencies when testing a recipe function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, f#

I have a function foo() that in turn calls function bar().  How can I confirm that bar actually gets called?

Example of *complex* business logic method to test:

```
class Car
{
  IStarter starter
  IKeyhole keyhole
  IBrakePedal pedal
  Drive()
  {
    keyhole.InsertKey()
    keyhole.RotateToStart()
    starter.TurnEngineOver()

    ...

    if (pedal.Pressed)
      this.SlowDown()
  }
}
```

I have a method that brings together 6 external dependencies (interfaces with methods), and runs them in a sequence, order is not important.  I would like to make sure each was called.  In another test, I'd like to tweak conditionals and ensure that a subset was called.

In C# with Moq, I have a full page of setup code.

Here's what I'd like to see in my unit test:

```
let `check that brake pedal slows down car` =
   let car = new Car()
   car.pedal.Pressed <- true
   car.Drive()
   car.SlowDown |> wasCalled
```

The rest should be inferred from usage.  I have a real need to reduce noise in tests.

Comment: you mean as in checking code coverage?

Comment: So... have you considered using a code coverage tool?

Comment: are you aware of mocks / stubs?

Comment: You seem to have a pretty clear picture... Can you expand upon that idea? maybe some pseudocode?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for some BDD style testing F#? Have you seen TickSpec? http://tickspec.codeplex.com/

Comment: TickSpec is a lot like Cucumber on Ruby (read about it in RSpec book).  It's nice to know that it exists in dotNET.  But not what I have in mind.  On to typing up SUT and test into the question.

Comment: I think "a full page" to set up those mocks is a bit of an exaggeration... it's maybe 10 lines.

Comment: How would you like to write that test/mocks instead? Are you aiming for user acceptance kind of tests?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your beef is with setting up mocks... I ventured an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I know to what you want is an [AutoMockingContainer](http://blog.eleutian.com/2007/02/23/TestsAutoMockingIoCContainer.aspx).

In a nutshell, it's an IoC container that gives you a Car with all IStarter, IKeyhole, IBrakepedal stubbed out and wired to the Car instance, without you explicitly registering any of them. You then proceed to set your expectations as usual (in your case, "car.SlowDown() was called"), then call the method under test.

The specifics depend on the IoC container and mocking framework used. The original one was written with Windsor and an old version of Rhino Mocks, but now there are AMC for [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/AutoMocker.htm), Ninject, [Autofac + Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/wiki/Automocking), etc.

You could start with one of these and wrap it to make it more idiomatic in F#.

[It](http://www.colourcoding.net/blog/archive/2009/04/26/why-containers-shouldnt-auto-mock.aspx) [has](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/05/26/the-dangers-of-automocking-containers/) [its](http://altnetseattle.pbworks.com/w/page/12367942/Why%20We%20Stopped%20Using%20the%20Auto-Mocking%20Container%20and%20What%27s%20Next) [downsides](http://osherove.com/blog/2008/4/25/pros-and-cons-and-of-using-an-auto-mocking-container-in-your.html), it's not something I'd recommend using "by default".

Comment: I side with Derick Bailey.  We are covering a pile of *code* with unit tests, oblivious to the grossly erroneous amount of coupling.